# i have trouble assigning a vector to another vector. The program crashes

Tags: c++, vector, stl, crash, assign

This is a shortened version of my actual code. This doesn't run too.
The line

```
tempPurchaseAndID[0] = tempPurchase;
```

causes the crash.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    string* strTempPurchase = new string("", "");
    string* tempOneID = new string("", "");
    vector<string> temp;//if category name exists in his purchase
    vector<string*/*size of two*/> tempPurchase;
    vector<string*/*size of two*/> oneID;// vector for one id

    vector<string*>* tempPurchaseAndID{};
    tempOneID[0] = "2222";

    oneID.push_back(tempOneID);
    strTempPurchase[0] ="milk";
    strTempPurchase[1] = "3";
    tempPurchase.push_back(strTempPurchase);
    tempPurchaseAndID[0] = tempPurchase;
    tempPurchaseAndID[1] = oneID;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone see the problem and suggest a solution?
Thanks in advance.

P.S. I need the pointers for other things so i can't delete the pointers

Comment: Don't use these pointers all over! This will probably fix your problem.

Comment: But i need it for other things in my project

Comment: Sounds weird you should need them, usually you wouldn't. You probably have a serious design flaw in your _real project_.

Comment: You don't allocate any memory for `tempPurchaseAndID` but you try to overwrite its elements.

Comment: How do I solve it then?

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out, your problems start with pointers.

Firstly `vector<string*>* tempPurchaseAndID{};` is not a vector but a null-pointer. Deferencing the null-pointer with `tempPurchaseAndID[0]` leads to a segfault.

It would be better to use just a vector, not a pointer to a vector:

```
vector<vector<string*> > tempPurchaseAndID;
```

But even now, your program would still crash in the same line but this time because of another reason: `tempPurchaseAndID` would have 0-length and there is no element with index 0 in it! So  it is better to use `push_back`, adding elements to the vector at the end:

```
tempPurchaseAndID.push_back(tempPurchase);
tempPurchaseAndID.push_back(oneID);
```

Try to reduce the usage of the pointers - they are a source for a lot of errors and bugs.

Comment: I did 

    vector<string*>* tempPurchaseAndID{};

because I need an array of vectors of arrays of strings.

Yes it's complicated, but that's what I need.

That's why I can't push back because 

    tempPurchaseAndID

an array not a vector

Comment: @user4384866 then you need vector<vector<string*> > and could still use push_back(). However vector of vector of pointers to string is a pretty complicated construct and not easy to work with...

Comment: so you think a vector will be better here instead of an array?

Comment: @user4384866 I don't know your project, but  vector is more flexible and is a better choice for most cases. However if you want to have an array you should declare it as one: `vector<string*> tempPurchaseAndID[2]` because `vector<string*>*` is only a pointer no memory is allocated per se.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` supports the [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) already, same for `std::string`.

I don't see any reason why you are messing with pointers here. Copying pointers won't give you what you probably want to achieve.

Comment: OK, but do you know what the problem is?

Comment: @user4384866 Of course, the problem is you are using pointers as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You're moving passed the first string and attempting to write to a string that just isn't there here:

```
strTempPurchase[0] ="milk";
strTempPurchase[1] = "3";
```

Then you do something similar here, with the added problem that you never actually create an instance of strTempPurchase:

```
tempPurchaseAndID[0] = tempPurchase;
tempPurchaseAndID[1] = oneID;
```

Also note that handling vectors through pointers is not ideal. If you resize the vector (using push_back, for example) the vector can move its data to another location, thus invalidating your pointers.

Comment: Oh I think I understand. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: There's a bunch of things you could do. Chances are you don't need those pointers since your strings and vectors are in main. Meaning they'll exist until program exits. If you really, really need to pass pointers to them you can just use address of operator.

For the strings, if you need a pair of strings I'd suggest using a container, perhaps std::pair<string, string> (or pointers thereof).